# Если вы все же забудете (про)инициализировать переменные?

Tags: java

Если вы все‐же забудете (про)инициализировать переменные, Java сама  присвоит
ноль числовым переменным, false переменных типа boolean, и
специальный код ‘\u0000’ переменным типа char.
Прочитал в книге. 
Как я понял "Если вы все же забудете (про)инициализировать переменные, Java сама просвоит ... то есть декларация?
В плане  `int a;`   это означает что я забыл (про)инициализировать переменную?
Объясните этот момент по подробнее.

Comment: Да, в плане `int a;` Какие ещё подробности вам нужны?

Comment: Речь, кстати, только про значения по умолчанию для полей. С локальными переменными такие фокусы не пройдут

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку Regent!!!

Comment: Ваша мысль непонятна. Что именно вы хотели спросить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем,в объекта или в экземпляра класса(называйте как хотите) есть такая штука,как переменные экземпляра.Это все переменные,которые описаны вне методов.Например:

```
public class Car{
String name;
String mark;
}
```

Все эти переменные являются переменными экземпляра.Допустим,создали вы объект класса Car

```
Car car = new Car();
```

Тем самым,автоматом инициализируются переменные экземпляра значениями по-умолчанию.
Чтобы проверить это можно сделать следующее :

```
system.out.println(car.name);
system.out.println(car.mark);
-----
null    
null
```

Но!Когда дело доходит до методов,то там объявленные переменные не буду инициализироваться по-умолчанию!Например:

```
public void start(){
   int benzinML;
   system.out.println(benzinML);
   //У вас будет синтаксическая ошибка : 
   The local variable benzin may not have been initialized.    
}
```